# Mars' Moons and its Dynamo

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, orbital-motion, planets

Given we could move Mars' moons, Phobos and Deimos, closer to each other, such that the gravitational effect between Mars and its moons is similar to the effect that Earth and its moon have on each other; would it be possible to trigger a dynamo effect within the Martian core?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean moving them closer to Mars. Given their extremely small mass, my complete wild guess is they would have to be orbiting deep inside of Mars to have anything like the Earth-Moon interaction.

Comment: no, i mean if the two moons moved closer to each other, not closer to mars. in such a configuration the moons would double their tidal forces against mars. similar to the effect the earth's moon has on earth's dynamics.

Comment: Compared with the Moon, Phoebos and Deimos are truly tiny. Each is less than 15 miles (25km) in diameter. They have essentially no effect on Mars at all.

Comment: ... .. ... sadness :/